# Cross compilation - V8 and Linux on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cross-compiling, v8

I am trying to embed Google's V8 in my game engine. I'm targeting 3 operating systems: Windows, Linux and OS X.

I haven't had any problems with building for Windows - I used NuGet packages. But I'm trying to build V8 for Linux and the problem is - I'm doing this on Windows (Windows 10 if it matters).

Google doesn't exactly say how to compile V8 for Linux using Windows and now I'm really confused, as I have no idea. So far I have depot_tools, properly fetched v8 (using fetch command), Python and MinGW.

I've tried with v8gen.py, but it seems that it generates build files only for Visual Studio. As I said, I don't need VS files.

My question is: What should I do?

Comment: How are you going to release a Linux version of your game without ever running it on Linux to test it?

Comment: @KenWhite Are you saying it's not possible or it's not smart? Those are two very different things. I'd say it's perfectly fine for prototyping. You make a build and send it to a friend.

Comment: @luk32: I'm not saying it's not possible. I'm saying it's a really poor idea to expect to write software for an OS without ever running it on that OS. You can't possibly know if it works at all, much less properly, without a copy of that OS to test on. Blindly expecting to be able to recompile it for a different OS and dump it out to people isn't going to turn out well. If you've got a friend that's stupid enough to run software that you've not even run first, send them my way. I've got some bridges to sell, and some ways they can get very rich for a minor investment of a few thousand $.

Comment: Why not run a VM? It's probably easier than trying to do cross-compilation and you get the advantage of being able to test your software and the added advantage of gaining experience with an operating system that isn't Windows, which is always handy to have.

Comment: Atm I don't have the abillity to do it, but I'm going to be able to do it soon. However, I'd like to build it now to not waste time.

Comment: @KenWhite You are overthinking this. Did you ever hear of cross-compilation? It does work, it can be useful. There is software out there which are generic linux amd64 binaries. It's exactly the same. "*Blindly expecting to be able to recompile it for a different OS and dump it out to people isn't going to turn out well.*" - Yet it works. I don't get your point about friends, and (I suppose) scamming schemes... Why do you even bring up some malicious agenda?

Comment: @luk32: I'm not overthinking anything. Cross-compilation is fine. Stupidly thinking cross-compilation works without needing any testing on the targeted OS does not. If your friends are stupid enough to run software that you've not even tested, they're idiots. It's not malice. It's pointing out the fact they lack basic intelligence. They're the sort that Nigerian princes love, because they're not smart enough to use common sense. You know, the Nigerian royalty who emails because they need help to get their inheritance out, but need some $$ sent to them as a sign of good faith?

Comment: It's free and easy to run a linux vm in windows.  I suggest not fighting the system and just going with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible out-of-the-box with the current build tools and configurations that V8 provides. As suggested in the comments, using a VM might be the quickest way to get this working for you.

If it is very important for you long-term, or for other developers as well, you could look at submitting patches to V8 to make this possible, but I don't have a good sense of how much work that would be.